# C# from sql db build a parent child tree

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I need some inputs with a `parentChild` object using `ASP.NET C# + Entity Framework`.

**Objective**: return an object composed by `parent` and `children` to `ASP.NET View`

**My class (db table):**

```
public class Organo
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int key { get; set; }
    public int parent { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Organo> OrganoChildrens { get; set; }
}
```

**Data example:**

```
id  |  key  |  parent  |  name  |  text
----+-------+----------+--------+----------
1       1        0          A       A
2       2        1          B       B   
3       3        1          C       C   
4       4        2          B1      B1  
5       5        4          B1_1    B1_1
6       6        1          D       D
```

**My controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> index()
{
        //get all data
        var organos = await db.Organos.ToListAsync();

        Organo organo_ = new Organo();

        foreach (var item in organos)
        {
            //head of diagram   
            if(item.parent == 0)
            {
                organo_.id = item.id;
                organo_.key = item.key;
                organo_.parent = 0;
                organo_.name = item.name;
                organo_.text = item.text;
            }
            else
            {
                //child
                Organo organoChild_ = new Organo();
                organoChild_.id = item.id;
                organoChild_.key = item.key;
                organoChild_.parent = item.parent;
                organoChild_.name = item.name;
                organoChild_.text = item.text;
                organo_.OrganoChildrens.Add(organoChild_);
            }
        }

        return View(fishbone_);
}
```

**But with this I only get the first level of children**.

How I build an hierarchical of `Parent -> Child1 -> Child2 of Child1...` ?

Many thanks

Comment: Use recursion to loop through the parent's children when it's a parent.

Comment: In the 2nd else? Could please give me some ideia?

Comment: Is there only one head of diagram?

Comment: Yes, only one head

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> index()
    {
            //get all data
            var organos = await db.Organos.ToListAsync();
            var populatedOrgano = PopulateChildren(organos.Single(x => x.parent == 0));


            return View(populatedOrgano);
    }

    public Organo PopulateChildren(Organo sourceOrgano, ICollection<Organo> organos) 
    {
        Organo organo_ = new Organo();
        var children = organos.Where(x => x.parent == sourceOrgano.id);
        foreach (var child in children)                 
        {
            //child
            Organo organoChild_ = new Organo();
            organoChild_.id = child.id;
            organoChild_.key = child.key;
            organoChild_.parent = child.parent;
            organoChild_.name = child.name;
            organoChild_.text = child.text;
            organo_.OrganoChildrens = new List<Organo>();
            organo_.OrganoChildrens.Add(organoChild_);
            PopulateChildren(child, organos);
        }
        return organo_;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, there might be some weirdness with the newing up of Organos but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I'm getting an error here:  

organo_.OrganoChildrens.Add(organoChild_);

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Check out my edit, you just have to new up the list of OrganoChildrens before you add to it.